# add timestamp in the log file on daily basis

Tags: apache, logging, log4j

I want to add the timestamp at the end of my log file on the daily basis.
Means for every day the log file should look like 
test.2013-01-10.log

My new log.properties file is below.Please help

```
log4j.rootLogger=info,myapp
log4j.appender.myapp=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myapp.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.myapp.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.myapp.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd}%m%n
log4j.appender.myapp.file=${catalina.base}/logs/myapplog/test
log4j.appender.myapp.DatePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd
#log4j.appender.myapp.MaxFileSize=999MB
#log4j.appender.myapp.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.myapp.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.logger=info,stdout,myapp
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=warn
```

Comment: what is the problem that you are having?

Comment: your current configuration will create the log file with format that you want..what's the problem?

Comment: i get the log file with name test.log but not the date with it

Answer (score 0):

Try use DailyRollingFileAppender instead of RollingFileAppender in your configuration

EDIT :

Try this. It will generate test.log and when your computer date changed, it will generate new test.log and test.logyyyy-mm-dd

log4j.properties :

```
log4j.rootLogger=info,A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern='.'%d{yyyy-mm-dd}
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd}%m%n
log4j.appender.A1.File=c:/test.log
log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
#log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=999MB
#log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.logger=info,stdout,A1
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=warn
```

Code :

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class test {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger barlogger = Logger.getLogger(test.class);
            barlogger.info("test");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to change your log to .txt, change this:

```
log4j.appender.A1.File=${catalina.base}/logs/test.log
```

to:

```
log4j.appender.A1.File=${catalina.base}/logs/test.txt
```

Comment: same result with DailyRollingFileAppender also.

in the logs i get the date with 'yyyy-mm-dd' but i want this pattern with my log file
i want my log file to be generated like test.2013-01-10

Comment: Hi Iswanto,
thanks for your intrest in solving my problem
still the same result

See what i have done to make the logs is
1)placed a jar file log4j in lib folder of my application deployed in Apache tomcat 7

2) placed the log4j.properties file in web-inf folder.

it creates the log file also but not with the time stamp.

Do i have to change some settings of the tomcat ?

Comment: Have you try to change your server time?

Comment: if you mean to say the system time

i have already done that.

Comment: Have you comment this part? #log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=999MB
#log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=20

Comment: I try to deploy servlet+log4j in tomcat and everything is ok..Try to use my log4j.properties and see if the problem still happen.

Comment: in your log.propertes can i change the file path from c:/test.log to my own.

yes i have commented that part

Comment: i have used your properties file just changed the file path from c:/test.log to mine 


but the problem still exist

Comment: My log file now creates the file with the date but the format of the file is of type file not .txt. will you please help me in this

Comment: hi iswanto, 

I want to create a file with name as

test_yyyy-mm-dd.txt can you please help me in doing this

Comment: are you using DailyRollingFileAppender? can you update your log4j.properties in your question?